# Angular view (DOM elements) not being updated when model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Running latest stable version of Angular in latest stable Chrome. I have an ng-click on a DOM element that's inside a view with ng controller A, but the DOM element itself has an ng-controller set to *another* controller, B. ng-click fires inside controller B, however changes to scope properties, which DOM element is bound to by its ng-model attribute, are not reflected.

Specifically I have a textarea, as well as other HTML5 input types. No errors, and when I break in the debugger, I can look at the scope variable and see that $scope is in fact pointing to controller B.

Plnkr example here, notice how it only updates the input that's inside the same DIV?: http://plnkr.co/edit/DmccNj?p=preview

Comment: Can you post a Plunker or at least some code?

Comment: Josh, working on one now.

Comment: most likely a scope inheritance issue due to using a primitive in scope.... read this and try the `dot` recommendation https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance

Comment: Notice how in the Plunker it only updates one of the two inputs, not the one in a different div, even though they have the same controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue just recently. Apparently, when you create two HTML fragments with the same `ng-controller`, it creates two separate instances of the controller. So, hitting the 'EDIT' button sets `$scope.comment` in instance 1, but the input field is bound to instance 2 of the controller.

If you must do it this way, you're best of creating an angular service, as they are singletons.

Here is my question: [Splitting HTML components for one controller causes controller to stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607728/splitting-html-components-for-one-controller-causes-controller-to-stop-working)

Also, [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/related) is a very cool Chrome extension from the AngularJS team to debug Angular applications. I mention this because if you (or I) had used this, we would have instantly seen what was going wrong.

Comment: You were so right. Thank you. Service makes more sense the more I thought about it.

Comment: xbones or anyone else, not sure if this deserves a new question, but when setting one of the scope variables that a <select> is bound to, it doesn't seem to update. Text boxes work, does Angular not support two way binding for <select> ?

Comment: @brushleaf:See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817728/need-example-of-select-usage-in-angularjs-input-form

Comment: xbonez, I am doing pretty much that, and in the service's $on() that I now have set up, I set the scope for various properties, and only the textarea and radio buttons are updating. the selects are not updating.

Comment: xbonez I see why. I was setting the ng-model property to an object that was semantically the same (same properties/values), but not the same object identity. That means doing a find on another array to get the reference to the right object. Seems noisy in the code.

Comment: @brushleaf, normally, a controller is associated with _one_ particular view/part of the page.  A view should project some part of your model onto the page.  Each view needs an associated controller from which it can get its data (i.e., the controller's $scope contains the pieces of the model that the view needs to project).  As was discussed above, if two or more views need access to the same data, put that data into a service, and have the controller's inject it.  But sometimes, one view (and hence one controller) is sufficient.

Comment: Batarang is great, although it seems to be hiding things. For instance all of the functions in my scopes are null, even though they're not. Why would that be the case?