# AngularJS - Does using the same controller in a hierarchy use separate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When you use the same controller as below in a DOM Hierarchy, does each controller gave its own scope/state?

```
<div ng-controller="EventController">
  Root scope <tt>MyEvent</tt> count: {{count}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in [1]" ng-controller="EventController">
      <button ng-click="$emit('MyEvent')">$emit('MyEvent')</button>
      <button ng-click="$broadcast('MyEvent')">$broadcast('MyEvent')</button>
      <br>
      Middle scope <tt>MyEvent</tt> count: {{count}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in [1, 2]" ng-controller="EventController">
          Leaf scope <tt>MyEvent</tt> count: {{count}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can't work out how the event broadcasting works in this example http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Regards

I

Comment: Yes, each declaration of the controller creates a new scope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776397/angular-view-dom-elements-not-being-updated-when-model-changes/15776866#15776866

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each instance of controller has its own scope. So in this case you have 4 scopes.
They are organized like this:
-- Root scope
---- Middle scope
------ Leaf scope
------ Leaf scope
How event broadcasting works in this example:
- when you press broadcast button, event is sent to the children scopes. Since broadcast button is in Middle scope, $broadcast is called on Middle scope and event is sent to both Leaf scope's. It is also sent to the sender, which is Middle scope.
- when you press emit button, event is sent to parent scopes. Again, emit button is in Middle scope and event will be sent to its parent, Root scope. Event is also sent to sender, which is Middle scope.